Error No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available after adding custom login page configuration in spring 6 mvc app
I am using tomcat 10.1.24 and jdk 21 with below dependencies details.
    <spring.version>6.0.10</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>6.0.4</spring.security.version>
    <spring.data.version>3.1.1</spring.data.version>

In my controller I do have requestmappings as below.
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ViewMapping(key="mytasks",label="My Tasks",hidden=false)
    public String getIndex(Model model,Locale locale){
        log.debug("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        return "index";
    }

In my security-config.xml I have minimal configuration.
<http auto-config="true">  
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="authenticated"/>  
    <form-login />  
    <http-basic />    
    <csrf disabled="true" />
</http>
//omitted other details

and below is my mvc-config.xml which was holding all the mvc configuration.
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp.cc.controller,com.mycomp.cc.ui.common"  />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />   
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

And finally web.xml to load my web application.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
         version="4.0">
         
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml         
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Above configuration is working fine and as expected I am getting spring default login page and after logging in able to see index page with all the details.
But now I want to add my own custom page so I have modified the security-context.xml as below and also added login requestmapping.
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/> 
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" /> 
        <http-basic />    
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>   
  //omitted other details

But after this configuration change I started getting below error
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.

Full log available HERE

the example you are referring to is using spring security, 2.6.4 the current version is 3.3.x. The example is over 2 years old and a new major version has bene released. I recommend you use the docs for learning as the code you have referenced is pretty outdated.

it might be outdated but still relevant and I do have different version but for the reference I am referring the example to make it more concise.

In my application I have these version but the error is the same <spring.version>6.0.10</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>6.0.4</spring.security.version>
<spring.data.version>3.1.1</spring.data.version>
<hibernate.version>6.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>

I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as providing a single line of xml, some random project and a stacktrace and thinking we can answer this? I suggest you provide a minimal reproducible example that we can run and get the same result in as little effort as possible. Good luck

Sorry it was too late so didnt update the question but added it now.

As the error suggests that Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext. I had to modify my web.xml to load Spring Security and Spring MVC in the main app context as updated below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
         version="4.0">
         
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security-config.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/mvc-servlet.xml         
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

More information on this behavior can be found HERE and HERE.
